# Run CRON job 5 times a day as it is shown in the table

Tags: linux, shell, cron, jobs

this table I will be updated every month,
How I can linking the table with crontab to run a shell scripts?
-The table will be like this for all days in the month-

```
 1 Apr  4:59    6:25    12:41   16:13   18:56   20:26
 2 Apr  4:58    6:23    12:40   16:13   18:57   20:27
 3 Apr  4:58    6:23    12:40   16:13   18:57   20:27
 4 Apr  4:55    6:21    12:40   16:13   18:58   20:28
 5 Apr  4:54    6:20    12:40   16:14   18:59   20:29
 6 Apr  4:52    6:18    12:39   16:14   19:00   20:30
 7 Apr  4:51    6:17    12:39   16:14   19:00   20:30
 8 Apr  4:49    6:16    12:39   16:14   19:01   20:31
 9 Apr  4:48    6:15    12:38   16:14   19:02   20:32 
 10 Apr 4:47    6:13    12:38   16:14   19:02   20:32
```

Comment: Please do the tour of StackOverflow where it tells you not to post pictures of code or data (because they are hard to parse), then click [edit] and update your question.

Comment: This seems rather *"picky"* or fine-grained for `cron` and you haven't explained where the numbers come from or what happens in June or September. It seems likely you'll be better off writing a custom script that runs all the time and decides itself when to do stuff.

Comment: Please click [edit] again and select your code/table with the mouse and then click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format it as code.

Comment: the script is already has been written to do what i want -play sound in the specific time from table - , but i don't know how to run it exactly according to the time in the table

Comment: Maybe [at](https://opensource.com/article/21/8/linux-at-command) is more appropriated.

Answer (score 2):

`at` is your friend.

Using this loop will create a job for every point in time you need to run your script:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){system("echo playsound.sh |  at "$i" "$2" "$1)}}' < timetable.txt
```